# Rotating points in a binary grid

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

Im making a binary tetris program in C based off of [this project](https://gist.github.com/aemkei/1672254). The 8 x 8 grid is represented by an `unsigned long`, where 0's indicate empty spaces and 1's filled spaces. Another `unsigned long` is used to represent a peice. The github page described the basic concept like this:

> The Board:
>
> ```
>                   00000         .....
> 798               11000   =>    ##... 
>                   11110         ####.
> ```
>
> The Block
>
> ```
> 3                 00011  =>     ...##
> ```
>
> Checking for Collision
>
> ```
>                   00000         .....
> 798&3 = 2         00000  =>     .....
>                   00010         ...X.
> ```
>
> ...

How could I extend these concepts to also apply to rotating a block *without* resorting to arithmatical operators?

Comment: you can move a point with `<< 1` (left) or `>>1` (right). Not sure if I understand well your question

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL thank you for your comment! im sorry if it was a bit confusing, I meant I want to rotate a set of points, for example, a 90 degree rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each block you have to decide what is the gravity center.

You can then have an array of functions for each block that will be a bit like sprites for 2d chars:

Your board:

```
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
0000000000
```

Your piece 3:

```
block_value = 0b11 << 16  // located on the right side, two rows before end
0b00000011
0b00000000
0b00000000
// rotate left
int mask = 1 << (__builtin_ctz(block_value) + 1);
block_value = block_value ^ mask | (mask << 9);
// this will give you the following block:
0b00000010
0b00000010
0b00000000
0b00000000
rotate left
// algo to transform it 90 degrees
rotate left
// algo to transform it 90 degrees
rotate left
back to first item
```

you store these operations as function pointers in two arrays of 4 functions pointers that will be called depending on if you rotate left or right, and you apply logical AND:

```c
current_index += rotation; //(+1 for left, -1 for right for example, or clockwise)
current_index = (current_index + 4) & 3; // to make sure you remain in the boundaries of your fptr array
if (rotation == 1)
    block_value = fptr_right[current_index](block_value); // call the transformation function
else // if (rotation == -1)
    block_value = fptr_left[current_index](block_value); // call the transformation function
```

Let me know if its helpful enough